# PHP Textbox writing to .md file

Tags: php, file-handling

I'm creating a little application for myself to handle my .md file that contains my todo list etc.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50" value="<?php include("me.md"); ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "me.md";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Whenever I enter a value into the textbox and click submit, the file doesn't update and stays the same. I have a feeling it might be that the submit button i s submitting the value of the blank file, but i there a work around for this? I need to be able to edit the file, not wipe it and start again. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <!--<input type="text" name="text_box" size="50" value="<?php //echo file_get_contents('me.md'); ?>"/>-->
            <textarea name="text_box" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo file_get_contents('me.md'); ?></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "me.md";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"; //Refresh the same page
    }

?>
```

Comment: That doesn't exactly achieve what I want to do, I need to edit the whole document, not add a new line.

Comment: Refresh the page after submitting by http-equiv meta attribute and use textarea instead of the textbox

Comment: It works! But it has this odd spacing, I'm sure it'll be fine however!

Comment: Updated my solution. It is reading the white space because <textarea> closing tag and PHP tag is on a new line. Maintain in one line.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('me.md'); ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) {
        file_put_contents("me.md", $_POST['text_box']);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the comment from this bit of code `$myFileContents .= "\n";`?

Comment: That wouldn't create the effect i need. I need to edit and update the text on the .md file. Not create new lines.